# Setting up MaxQuant parameters for processing proteomics data

Tags: proteins, proteomics, meta-analysis, maxquant

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18850/processing-proteomics-data).

In relevance to my research, I've been looking for proteomics data (control vs. diabetic) and I found a dataset in the article "Diabetes causes marked inhibition of mitochondrial metabolism in pancreatic β-cells" (figures from here: [link](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31171772/)).
I want to process RAW files from this proteomics experiment. I'm trying to set up the analysis in MaxQuant and I am looking for some help in defining some parameters.

Sample:
PRIDE dataset (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pride/archive/projects/PXD012979). I want to analyse
8 sample files (please find the file labels and appropriate condition labels below).

Instrument used to generate the data:
Orbitrap Fusion Lumos

Method:
Label free quantification

Modifications:

Groups/condition:
Diabetic vs. Control

Diabetic mice
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_554_F30
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_545_F11_544_F33
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_554_M3
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_582_M1

Control mice
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_544_F13
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_544_F31
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_582_M13
FL0408_MSQ911_MariaRohm_544_M1

Modifications:
Fixed:
Oxidation(M)
Deamidation NQ

Variable:
Carbamidomethyl(C)

My objective is to get the values of the normalized abundance (kindly find the figure below from the article associated with this dataset, for 4 control vs. 4 diabetic samples) from MaxQuant analysis.

Abundance (shown in the paper):
[image]

MaxQuant setup:
I'm not sure what has to be filled in the fields circled in red. Could someone please have a look?
Should the fraction be set to 1? I am not sure what has to be filled for the dataset in the link that I shared above.
[image]

Label min. ratio coun -- should this be 1? I am not sure what this means.
[image]

Should the following fields be checked?
[image]